# Targeting specific column in table

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table of class `players` with 5 columns and 40 rows. I want to make the second column have `width: 200px`.

I can not figure out how to select the specific column in the table. So far I have narrowed it down to this, but this does it to all of the rows in the table. Can someone help me set the column width for a specific column?

```
table.players td 
{

}
```

Comment: Never mind.  I figured it out.  Im a big boy now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work (except on IE8 and below):

```
table.players td:nth-child(2) { width: 200px; }
```