# Making text in one column italics with CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the text in one column italics using CSS. Currently, the structure of my table is the following, but I cannot get the text on the right column to be in italics.

CSS (in the head section):

```
<style>
        .col-right-col{
            font-style: italic;
        }
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="col-left-col">
        <col class="col-right-col">
    </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Left Col Header</th>
      <th scope="col">Right Col Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Left</td>
      <td>Row 1 Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Left</td>
      <td>Row 2 Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 Left</td>
      <td>Row 3 Right</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: According to [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/styling-col-and-or-colgroup/6949/2) there are [only 4 properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns) you can style like that, and font-style isn't one of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Targeting specific column in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287101/targeting-specific-column-in-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is using the `td:nth-child()` to make Row 1/2/3 Right italic:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: @SauronTheDark You accepted this answer (which uses the same technique as described in the proposed duplicate), but you also say it is not working. Which is it?

Comment: The one you proposed I tried and this one here worked. The problem is that I was expecting results on Dreamweaver, but did not get them. I went ahead and published the CSS (the production site is on Wordpress) and it worked. Since the CSS rule I posted is exactly the same as the answer I accepted, I chose that one. But I wish to clarify that both approaches work.